# Bottom Sheet Behavior peek height also including the height of the bottom navigation view in phone with notch

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a fragment with a bottom sheet inside coordinator layout. I am setting the peak height of the sheet as 60 dp. It looks fine on a phone without a notch.
But in a phone with a notch, it is also including the height of the bottom navigation view of the phone. So lets say if the height of bottom navigation is also 60 dp then the bottom sheet is showing a peak height of 120 dp instead of 60 dp. Testing on Samsung M31.

Layout file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/scanner_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/dp_150"
            android:background="@color/dashboard_bg"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_25"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_40"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_25">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_imageview"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_50"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_50"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/company_details_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_15"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_25"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/logo_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/logo_imageview">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                    android:text="@string/welcome"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_4"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
                    android:text="@string/company_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/help_imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_help"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/company_details_linear_layout" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_25"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/help_imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/company_details_linear_layout" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_6"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_8"
                android:drawableTint="@color/error_red"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                android:text="@string/verify_your_account"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/error_red"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/company_details_linear_layout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/company_details_linear_layout"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            layout="@layout/dashboard_bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/dp_60"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void BottomSheetBehavior.setGestureInsetBottomIgnored(boolean gestureInsetBottomIgnored)
```

Sets whether this bottom sheet should adjust it's position based on the system gesture area on Android Q and above.